# Where can I download the Sybase ASE 12.5 installer?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I need to test a project working on this version of sybase. I have searched for the installer on the sap website but it seems that it is no longer available for download in the developer version.

Where can I find it?

Comment: I have checked as well and they mention that v12 is not available for free download anymore. you may contact SAP/Sybase office or dealers and ask them for help. More info: http://www.sypron.nl/get_ase_soft.html

Comment: This answer is not very encouraging.
Will there be a website with an image of the installer?

Comment: ASE 12.5 was made end of life in 2009 so you're looking at a version which is over a decade out of vendor support which is why it's not readily available.

Comment: I am aware of this. 
But believe me. In LATAM there are still large companies that use it.
I'm developing a project that needs to be compatible with that version and I haven't been able to set up a test environment with this version.

Comment: If you have a relationship with one of the LATAM companies that are still using `ASE 12.5.x`, have you tried contacting (one of) them about getting a copy of their installation package?

Comment: fwiw, a general comment ... Sybase/SAP has opted to **not** distribute versions of ASE with known security issues; I'm pretty sure this applies to the old 12.5.x versions of the software; granted, this doesn't mean the software can't be used, and obviously there are companies still running the old software, but the point is that even contacting Sybase/SAP directly may not be very productive (unless you happen to be a large customer with a bit of 'pull' with the Sybase/SAP sales & support teams)